# Why the variable type becomes any?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Update 1:

mxGraph.d.ts full code:

```js
declare module 'mxgraph' {

  class mxGraph {

    constructor(container: HTMLElement);
  
  }
}
```

index.d.ts full code:

```js
declare module 'mxgraph' {
  export interface mxGraphExportObject {
    mxGraph: typeof mxGraph;
  }

  export type mxGraphOptions = {
    mxBasePath?: string;
  };

  export default function (options?: mxGraphOptions): mxGraphExportObject;
}
```

---

I am create a type declaration library for mxgraph package, primary code is:

```js
declare module 'mxgraph' {
  export interface mxGraphExportObject {
    mxGraph: typeof mxGraph;
    // ...
  }

  export type mxGraphOptions = {
    mxBasePath?: string;
    // ...
  };

  export default function (options?: mxGraphOptions): mxGraphExportObject;
}
```

When I use in my project, all property type is `any` under `mx` namespace:

```js
import mxgraphFactory from 'mxgraph';

const mx = mxgraphFactory({
  mxBasePath: 'assets',
});

mx.mxGraph;
```

[image]

---

Type of `mx` is valid.

[image]

---

- type declaration library: https://github.com/typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph
- demo project(typed-mxgraph branch): https://github.com/hungtcs/react-with-mxgraph--ts-factory/tree/typed-mxgraph

Comment: You seem to have missed including `mxgraphFactory` in your question. What does it return?

Comment: @MikeS. This function provided by mxgraph package, is a function return an object.

Comment: @MikeS. I create a package named typed-mxgraph to provide typescript declarations for mxgraph package.

Comment: `typeof mxGraph` --- what is `mxGraph` in this type declaration?

Comment: @zerkms The `mxGraph` is a class included in the mxgraph module, the declaration file is https://github.com/typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph/blob/master/view/mxGraph.d.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying, I found out why, `index.d.ts` should use `/// <reference path="..." />` to reference other declaration files. this commit fix the issues https://github.com/typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph/commit/244b0124ae46d09793f4cb0af5262af8f4807079

Answer (score 1):

> Why the variable type becomes any?

You shouldn't have used `typeof` operator. `typeof` returns the type of value, thus it can be anything.

Consider this example:

```js
const foo: any = "bar";

type Foo = {
    bar: string;
}

type FooBar = {
    foo: typeof foo; // should not use typeof here
}

const foobar:FooBar = {
    foo: "abc"
};

foobar.foo
```

Here foobar.foo is of `any` type and it is still valid in typescript. Although `typeof` was not meant to be used like that.

[image]

## Solution:

Define `MxGraph` type first and

```js
export interface mxGraphExportObject {
    mxGraph: MxGraph;
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @bravemaster, typeof is used here because `mx.mxGraph` is a class instead of an instance of mxGraph.

Comment: You cannot get typescript type with javascript `typeof` operator. You will get something like `"object"` or `"function"`

Comment: I use `typeof` in some `.d.ts` file, this demo is work well https://github.com/hungtcs/react-with-mxgraph--ts-factory/blob/master/src/app/App.tsx, but not working with my current demo

Comment: @鸿则_ Why do you make your own type definition files (esp. for a third-party library)? `d.ts` files should be used when you are using typescript in your project and a library does not provide its own type definition files, or if you're going to publish a package to npm which has been written in typescript. Other than that, you don't need to write d.ts files.

Comment: @鸿则_  Seems like you're writing `@types` npm for a package. Anyway, I think using `typeof` for type assertion is completely wrong.

Comment: I am write a definition library for mxgraph, because this library do not provide an official `@types` package.

Comment: I seem to find the reason, add some `/// <reference path="./view/index.d.ts" />`, work well now : )